# Jitter points in gnuplot. Data input file format

Tags: gnuplot, jitter

I am able to successfully reproduce Jitter examples from here: http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/violinplot.html

However, when I try to use my own data, the points are not "jittered".

Here is the data file (data.dat):

```
10 1 1 3 8 8 8
20 2 2 3 8 8 8
30 3 3 3 8 8 8
```

Here is a minimal gnuplot input file:

```
set jitter
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2 with points, '' u 1:3 with points, '' u 1:4 with points, '' u 1:5 with points, '' u 1:6 with points, '' u 1:7 with points
```

The points are right on top of each other, whereas I want points that are in the same place to be slightly offset (x-axis).

I've installed the latest version of gnuplot:
$ gnuplot --version
gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 6

EDIT WITH SOLUTION:
@Ethan's comment cleared it up for me. I'm able to get the jittering by reorganizing my input data file so that it's a single dataset, which contains internal "collisions", rather than reading in lots of individual data sets. e.g:

```
10 1
10 1
10 3
10 3
20 2
20 2
30 8
30 8
```

And my gnuplot file is now just:

```
set jitter
plot 'data.dat' using 1:2 with points
```

Comment: jitter is applied to reduce collisions within a data set.  Your plot command reads 7 data sets, none of which contains internal collisions.  They just happen to come from the same file. I get it that you were expecting all 7 plots to be treated as a single set of points for the purpose of removing collisions, but that's not how it works.

Comment: Thanks @Ethan, you cleared it up for me. Can you write it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"set jitter" will not work across multiple data sets as noted in the comment.  You could do something similar by adding a random displacement in the 'using' specifier.

```
plot for [col=2:7] 'data.dat' using 1:(column(col) + (rand(0)-0.5)/2.) with points
```

This is different from "set jitter" because *all* points will be randomly displaced, whereas with jitter only overlapping points are shifted and the displacement is not random.

[image]

Alternatively, since in your case the columns are distinct perhaps you want to shift systematically based on the column number:

```
plot for [col=2:7] 'data.dat' using (column(1)+col/4.) : (column(col))
```

[image]